# Retrieve Outgoing number from broadcast Reciever android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create customized screen for outgoing calls. For which I would like to get outgoing number.

I was looking at this link which uses a separate broadreceiver for incoming and outgoing.

http://goo.gl/YUD1b5

But doesn't work. I get error message upon making a call

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

I have one broadcast receiver which has manifest:

```
     <receiver
        android:name="com.honey.ringer.PhoneListenerBroad"
        android:priority="999"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The broadcast receiver is called when ever I call out but I am not able to retrieve the out going call phone number. I am not sure what to do here:

Here is the broadcast receiver file:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
    c = context;

    try
    {
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
    }

}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    public void onCallStateChanged(final int state, final String incomingNumber) 
    {
        Handler callActionHandler = new Handler();

        Runnable runRingingActivity = new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Intent intentPhoneCall = new Intent(c, AcceptMakeCall.class);
                intentPhoneCall.putExtra("incomingnumber", incomingNumber);
                intentPhoneCall.putExtra("state", state);
                intentPhoneCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                c.startActivity(intentPhoneCall);
            }
        };

        if (state == 1)
        {
            callActionHandler.postDelayed(runRingingActivity, 100);
        }

        if (state == 0) 
        {
            callActionHandler.removeCallbacks(runRingingActivity);
        }

        if (state == 2)
        {
            /*callActionHandler.postDelayed(runRingingActivity, 100);*/


        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me to get the outgoing number?

Comment: intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER); in your reciever

Comment: first check your action of intent.if it is android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL then only you get the outgoing number

Comment: also use permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

Comment: how to check the outgoing call?

Comment: already given permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in your onRecieve


if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {

String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER); 
Log.e("Number=",number);

}


and using permission:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
This worked for me.Hope it works for you also
```